# Cannot generate a new controller via scoffolding in Entity/C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am taking a tutorial on getting started with Entity Framework and C#. 
I was following the [tutorial][1] and I am getting an error when I tried to create a new scaffolding item. When I select the Model class, data context class and select the controller name, I get the following error message:
**"There was an error running the selected code generator: 'There was an error getting the type 'ContosoUniversity.Models.Student'. Try rebuilding the project."**

I did rebuild the project, twice actually, and I keep getting this error message. Can anybody tell me what might be happening?

These are the steps I took to create the new scaffold item:

- Right-click the Controllers folder in Solution Explorer, select Add,
  and then click New Scaffolded Item.

  In the Add Scaffold dialog box, select MVC 5 Controller with views,
  using Entity Framework, and then choose Add. In the Add Controller
  dialog box, make the following selections, and then choose Add:

  Model class: Student (ContosoUniversity.Models). (If you don't see
  this option in the drop-down list, build the project and try again.)

  Data context class: SchoolContext (ContosoUniversity.DAL).

  Controller name: StudentController (not StudentsController).

  Leave the default values for the other fields.

This is how I have the code set up in my Student class file, under Models:

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
>
> namespace ContosoUniversity.Models
> {
>     public class Student
>     {
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public string LastName { get; set; }
>         public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
>         public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
>
>         public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
>     }
> }
> ```

Finally, this is how I have my connections set up to the localDB that is being used in the tutorial.

```
> <connectionStrings>
>     <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial
> Catalog=ContosoUniversity1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
> providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>   </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string

From this

```
<add name="xxx" connectionString="Data Source=xxx;initial catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

To this

```
<add name="xxx" connectionString="metadata=res://*/EFMOdel.csdl|res://*/EFMOdel.ssdl|res://*/EFMOdel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxxx;initial catalog=xxxx;persist security info=True;user id=xxxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```